# Angular, NgRx. Как сделать, чтобы в консоли браузера enum отображались не как числа а как строки?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Angular, NgRx.
Как сделать, чтобы в консоли браузера enum отображались не как числа а как строки?

Имеется:

```
serverStatus: ServerStatus
enum ServerStatus {
  Connected,
  ...
}
```

У меня выводится так

```
{serverStatus: 0}
```

Нужно, чтобы было так

```
{serverStatus: Connected}
```

Есть ли какая-то настройка для этого глобальная? Вариант ServerStatus[serverStatus] не интересует, т.к. нужно настроить для всего приложения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
enum S {A,B}
```

после компиляции в JS превращается в

```
{
  "0": "A",
  "1": "B",
  "A": 0,
  "B": 1
}
```

и никакими настройками это не поменять

---

Если ещё не поздно, то можно поменять enum

```
enum S {
 Connected='Connected'
}
```

он будет компилироваться в

```
{
  "Connected": "Connected"
}
```

и выводить то, что требуется

---

Вот тут полный список опций компилятора, которые могут в той или иной степени поменять его поведение https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig

Там есть одна "похожая" на нужную - [preserveConstEnums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#preserveConstEnums), но она не меняет поведение в рантайм.

> This essentially makes such const enums a source-code feature only, with no runtime traces.