# Как преобразовать строку в enum внутри цикла?

Tags: typescript

Помогите разобраться, есть цикл foreach, который перебирает некое перечесление (enum), внутри цикла вызывается функция, принимающая в качестве аргумента значения enum, но при переборе enum, его значения становится строкой, вопрос - как преобразовать его (значение) к enum?

Пример кода:

```
enum TrafficLight {
  Green = 1,
  Yellow,
  Red
}

for (const value in TrafficLight)  {
    function(value);
    // Но value в данном случаи string, а мне надо enum, т.е. например TrafficLight.Yellow
}
```

Comment: Что то не понятное вы делаете, а главное зачем?

Comment: Что непонятно? У меня есть enum, который перебирается в for, и мне надо получить значение типа enum, вместо string

Comment: А вы поинтересуйтесь что же на самом деле лежит в Enum https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgTgQwGZIJYGMAyqDmALAFygG8AoKKAcTmFCgF4oBGAGnKgE1gAbbgewDubCgCVgAE1IBfUqXR8QAZz7dgAOn44AFPGRosuQgEoA3EA

Comment: В общем кажется тут вам либо не нужен enum, либо нужно написать что-то другое.

Comment: буквально 2 дня назад https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1542771/340609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобный вопрос [разбирался уже на днях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1542771/340609)

В том виде, что ты определяешь enum, итератор вернёт 6 значений, 2 на каждый элемент, и ничего ты с этим не поделаешь.

Их можно откастовать опять к типу enum, смотри пример ниже.

```
enum TrafficLight {
  Green = 1,
  Yellow,
  Red
}

for (const value in TrafficLight)  {
    const v: TrafficLight = +(value.match(/\d+/) ? value : TrafficLight[value])
    console.log(value, "is green", v == TrafficLight.Green, "is yellow", v == TrafficLight.Yellow, "is red", v == TrafficLight.Red);
}


[LOG]: "1",  "is green",  true,  "is yellow",  false,  "is red",  false 
[LOG]: "2",  "is green",  false,  "is yellow",  true,  "is red",  false 
[LOG]: "3",  "is green",  false,  "is yellow",  false,  "is red",  true 
[LOG]: "Green",  "is green",  true,  "is yellow",  false,  "is red",  false 
[LOG]: "Yellow",  "is green",  false,  "is yellow",  true,  "is red",  false 
[LOG]: "Red",  "is green",  false,  "is yellow",  false,  "is red",  true
```

Если хочется иметь в итераторе не пару, а одно вхождение, то д.б.

```
enum TrafficLight { Green='Green', Yellow='Yellow', Red='Red'} 

for (const value in TrafficLight)  {
    const v: TrafficLight = value as TrafficLight
    console.log(value, "is green", v == TrafficLight.Green, "is yellow", v == TrafficLight.Yellow, "is red", v == TrafficLight.Red);
}

[LOG]: "Green",  "is green",  true,  "is yellow",  false,  "is red",  false 
[LOG]: "Yellow",  "is green",  false,  "is yellow",  true,  "is red",  false 
[LOG]: "Red",  "is green",  false,  "is yellow",  false,  "is red",  true
```

И кастовать значительно проще ^